# qt_create_translation doesn't change .ts file or create .qm file

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, translation

I created a small test project to show my problem:

`main.cpp`

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QPushButton button(QApplication::tr("Hello, World!"), nullptr);
    button.resize(200, 100);
    button.show();
    return QApplication::exec();
}
```

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

project(TestQtWidgetsProject)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

add_executable(TestQtWidgetsProject main.cpp)

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets)
target_link_libraries(TestQtWidgetsProject Qt::Core Qt::Gui Qt::Widgets)

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED LinguistTools)
qt_create_translation(QM_FILES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/translation_ru.ts)
```

I also created an empty file `translation_ru.ts` in the project root directory.

But after building the project the file `translation_ru.ts` remains empty and no .qm file is created in `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}`. Why?

Comment: Note that `qt_create_translation` is deprecated https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtlinguist-cmake-qt-create-translation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still haven't figured out why this code doesn't work, but as Alan Birtles said, the command is deprecated, so that might be the reason.

Here is a working code example for this project:

```
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED LinguistTools)

qt_add_translations(TestQtWidgetsProject
        INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
            ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
        TS_FILES
            translation_ru.ts)

add_dependencies(TestQtWidgetsProject update_translations)
```

Comment: Your first example does not work because the qm files stored in `QM_FILES` is not used at all so nothing is done with it. Add them to add_executable(). There is also no need to add a new target `update_translations` in your second example because those update targets are created [automatically](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtlinguist-cmake-qt-add-translations.html#description)

Comment: @chehrlic I tried to put `QM_FILES` into the `add_executable`, but that didn't work. Also the target, that is automatically added in `qt_add_translations`, is not the `update_translations`, but `${target}_lrelease`, so the `update_translation` target should be added manually.